# Encoding videos on iOS

Tags: ios, video, encoding, software-recommendation

I would like to convert some videos to H265, but this is quite slow on my Mac. I know that the modern A-series chips have hardware encoding/decoding support for H265. I would like to harness the power of the A12X on my iPad and use it for video encoding.

Is there any way to encode videos on iOS, perhaps an app on the App Store? On macOS there is HandBrake, which also has a command line tool called HandBrakeCLI, but I have not found something similar for iOS.

One idea would be to open the source video in iMovie and then export it with my desired settings. However, this sounds kind of hacky and would not offer the level of control that HandBrake does. Are there any better alternatives?